# How to strip &amp; from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 2.3.8

`name` has the value `Tiffany &amp; Co.`

This code in view:

```
@header_title = 'Related shops with ' + strip_tags(@shop.name)
```

yields result A:

```
#note that the &amp; has NOT been stripped
Related shops with Tiffany &amp; Co.
```

This code in view:

```
@header_title = strip_tags(@shop.name) + 'Related shops with '
```

yields result B:

```
#note that the &amp; HAS been stripped
Tiffany & Co. Related shops with
```

I actually want `Related shops with Tiffany & Co.` (i.e. convert the `&amp;` to `&`)

How do I do this?

Why is it that in the second call, the `&amp;` is stripped, but not so in the first call?

Comment: Is that a joke question? Replace second line by first?

Comment: It's not a joke. I have tried replacing in various position. I want the `@shop.name` at behind.

Comment: No difference with result A. I want the `&amp;` to show as `&`.

Comment: Your question was confusing, hence the "joke" above. Edited your question to make it clear what you want.

Comment: You might also want to try [htmlentities library](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) sometime in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A guess:

```
@header_title = ('Related shops with ' + strip_tags(@shop.name)).html_safe
```

In your example the `&amp;` isn't really stripped in either case. If the string isn't marked as html safe it is being escaped by default when added to view, so `&amp;` becomes `&amp;amp;` if you check the page source.

Alternative when `@header_title` isn't html safe and you are adding it to erb view:

```
<%= raw @header_title %>
```

This 'html safeness' is related to Rails XSS protection:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3

Note that you should use `html_safe` and `raw` only when you trust the contents of the string.

--edit

Edited the answer after testing in Rails 3 console. Still don't know why the order matters there.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :020 > ('Related shops with ' + helper.strip_tags("Tiffany &amp; Co.")).html_safe?
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :021 > (helper.strip_tags("Tiffany &amp; Co.") + 'Related shops with ').html_safe?
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :022 > ('Related shops with ' + helper.strip_tags("Tiffany &amp; Co.")).html_safe.html_safe?
 => true
```

--edit2

Further testing.. It looks like order matters when concatenating safe and unsafe strings.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :037 > safe = "This is html safe string".html_safe
 => "This is html safe string" 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :038 > not_safe = "This is not html safe string"
 => "This is not html safe string" 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :039 > (safe + not_safe).html_safe?
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :040 > (not_safe + safe).html_safe?
 => false
```

Comment: As you observe, a safe string plus an unsafe string equals a safe string, which is probably not always true. Another point of irritation is that `.html_safe` only declares something HTML safe without actually *making* it HTML safe.

Comment: Yes, `html_safe` is just for marking that the string content is trusted. Added mention about that to answer.